# WCF Data Service - update a record instead of inserting it

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm developing a WCF Data Service with self tracking entities and I want to prevent clients from inserting duplicated content. Whenever they POST data without providing a value for the data key, I have to execute some logic to determine whether that data is already present inside my database or not. I've written a Change interceptor like this:

```
[ChangeInterceptor("MyEntity")]
public void OnChangeEntity(MyEntity item, UpdateOperations operations){
  if (operations == UpdateOperations.Add)
  {
    // Here I search the database to see if a matching record exists.
    // If a record is found, I'd like to use its ID and basically change an insertion
    // into an update.
    item.EntityID = existingEntityID;
    item.MarkAsModified();
  }
}
```

However, this is not working. The existingEntityID is ignored and, as a result, the record is always inserted, never updated. Is it even possible to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hooray! I managed to do it.

```
item.EntityID = existingEntityID;
this.CurrentDataSource.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, EntityState.Modified);
```

I had to change the object state elsewhere, ie. by calling .ChangeObjectState of the ObjectStateManager, which is a property of the underlying EntityContext. I was mislead by the .MarkAsModified() method which, at this point, I'm not sure what it does.